# Why can't I delete my comment on this question?

Tags: bug, status-completed

I'm trying to delete a now irrelevant comment of mine on [this](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/5363/longest-forced-sequence-that-ends-with-checkmate-and-every-move-is-a-check/5376#) question, but I can't. The system hasn't blocked me from deleting comments for a day for deleting too many, so I think that the page is being buggy. I also can't interact with the comment flags, upvotes, or the "bookmarking" star either. What is wrong with the question page?

Comment: SE mods, as a chess mod I also can't delete (or edit) the comment.

Comment: Indeed. Which is why I have added the status-review tag to bring it to the attention of the level of mods above me.

Comment: I don't see any comments from you on the question itself. Can you clarify which one you want to remove, please? And also, what's happening when you try to delete it? Is the delete link not showing up, or do you get an error?

Comment: FWIW, I just flagged the comment for mod deletion by referring to this meta post. See whether the mod tool is possible to delete instead of trying to delete the comment from the post directly...

Comment: However, it seems really weird since you also mentioned comment flags, upvotes, and favorite (starring)... because I could flag the comment and also favorite the question just now. There doesn't seem any maintenances (read-only status) on that day either...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue has been fixed.

The root cause was an answer (which happened to be deleted, though the same thing could have happened on an undeleted answer) where the following was included `[StartPly "124"]`, which indicated a starting move on the 62<sup>nd</sup> move. The only problem is that there were no moves given, and this caused the `chess.js` script to crash. And due to the way that the script was initialized, it caused execution of other front-side initialization to not be processed, leading to click events not being attached to buttons, etc.

To fix this:

1. The actual bug in the chess.js script has been fixed to check for nulls on the proper line to avoid this from happening.
2. The way in which the chess.js script is called has been modified to ensure that issues on the script do not affect page init logic.